Upper bound on sum arising in the context of differential privacy
I stumbled upon the following practical problem when working on differential privacy.
Define
$$ \delta(\epsilon, N, F) := \sum_{k = 0}^N \binom{N}{k} \, p^k (1 - p)^{N - k}\, D(\epsilon, k),
$$
where
$$
\\ D(\epsilon, k) = \sum_{s = 0}^k \max{(0, \binom{k}{s} - e^\epsilon \binom{k}{s+1})},
\\ p = \frac{2}{F}, 
\\ F \in \mathbb{N}\;\; F \geq 2.
$$
In other words, $\delta$ is the average of $D$, w.r.t the binomial distribution.
I am interested in inverting this formula. That is, determine $N$ given $\epsilon$, $\delta$ and $F$. Since $D$ is decreasing with $k$, $\delta$ is decreasing with $N$ it is meaningful to define the desired quantity as
$$
\hat{N}(\epsilon, \delta, F) = \mathrm{argmin}_{N \geq 0}(\delta(\epsilon, N, F) \leq \delta)
$$
In principle, this can be done directly by evaluating $\delta$ followed by a binary search. But for small values of $\epsilon, \delta$, that is pretty inefficient - and I have very strict practical requirements (like, the computation should not take longer than a microsecond). So I was wondering if we can get some easy to evaluate estimates (or at least good ways to precompute values).
A few observations and questions:
When $N \rightarrow \infty$ and we fix $N / F := \lambda$, we arrive at
$$
\delta(\epsilon, \lambda) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda} D(\epsilon, k).
$$
This formula is helpful for precomputing values, because we have one parameter less. Numerical evidence suggests that this formula is an upper bound. But I am strugging with proving that. So, I am wondering if somebody can help here.
